# Value interdependency: difference between "ratio", "proportion", "rate", and "relation"

Tags: word-choice

In the context of decision-making, I'm looking for a word that describes the relation of two values: "even if value *a* increases, value *b* decreases". For this relation, I have found *ratio, proportion, rate* and *relation*. Which is the most suitable, when I want to use it in the following sentence: "To weigh out possible advantages, ??? between the values have to be established"?

Comment: a and b are inversely proportional [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics))

Comment: @Radu, that is not clear from the question.  "even if value a increases, value b decreases" is stated.  But maybe if value a decreases, value b would decrease even faster...

Comment: That would be black magic!

Answer (score 2):

The relation you specify is an "inverse dependency" or an "inverse proportion".

Answer (score 2):

The *even if*  phrase at the beginning of “even if value *a* increases, value *b* decreases” suggests that value *b* decreases independently of what value *a* does.  The phrase could be used in a sentence like “In previous times, *b* followed *a*; but in this time frame, even when *a* increases, *b* decreases.”

If instead you mean to say that increase in *a* implies  decrease in *b*, and conversely when *a* decreases, you can say  *b* changes oppositely to *a*, and *might* say  *b* changes inversely to *a*.  However, *inverse* typically refers to a multiplicative inverse.  If *a·b = k* for some constant *k*, then *a* and *b* are inversely related.  If instead *a+b = k*, you might speak of a *[zero-sum game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-sum_game)*.

In the sentence you ask about, none of *ratio, proportion, rate, relation, inverse, opposite, zero-sum* or variants thereof are appropriate.  Instead write

> To maximize advantage, *tradeoffs* between values must be established.

A *[tradeoff](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tradeoff#Noun)*
is “An advantage or improvement that necessitates the corresponding loss or degradation of something else”.